# Как сделать разделительную черту между ячейками таблицы?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть таблица, состоящая из двух ячеек в одной строке.
Как сделать так, чтобы между этими ячейками была вертикальная линия с помощью css или html?

Вот код:

```
<table frame="void" rules="cols">

<tr>

<td>ячейка 1</td>

<td>ячейка 2</td>

</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, `table td:first-child{border-right:1px #000 solid}` .